# How to assign multiple date formats to a variable

Tags: php, date, switch-statement

I am trying to make a script to trigger on a specific day,month,etc of the year.So i decided to use switch because i have like 3 cases.I want it to trigger weekly,monthly,and quarterly.Here is what i've done so far

```
$date=date('l,m,Y');
switch($date) {
 case (date('l')=="Monday"): //case 1:he should trigger every Monday
 echo 'weekly';
 break;
 case  (date('d')==01): //case 2:he should trigger every 01 or 1 of each month
 echo "monthly";
 break;
 case ...: //case 3:here i need some help...it should trigger every 3 months(quarterly),at the first day(01 or 1) after the quart
```

So in order to make this switch work,i need to format the $date,in other words to use date_format to change l into d and so on.But it doesnt work ... because to use date_format i also have to use date_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date = strtotime("6 Oct 2014"); //change this with "now" value
if (date('l', $date) == 'Monday'){}//if its monday,execute
if (date('d', $date) == "06"){}//if its 06 of the month,execute
if ( ((date('n',$date) % 3) == '1') && (date('d',$date) == "06") ){}// if its 06 of the month,and has passed 3 months(quarterly),execute
```

Put your codes inside every "if" statement,and if all 3 conditions are passed,it will execute it 3 times.